# Why is $A$ a compact operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

Let $X$ be a compact space and let $\mu$ be a positive Borel measure on X. Let $T\in \mathscr{B}(L^p(\mu),C(X))$ where $1\lt p \lt \infty$.

Show that if $A:L^p(\mu)\rightarrow L^p(\mu)$ defined by $Af=Tf$, then $A$ is a compact operator.

Here is an example: let $X=[0,1]$,$\mu$ is the lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$, p=2.

$\forall f\in L^2(0,1)$, define $T(f)=\int_0^1{f(x)e^{-ixy}}dx,y\in[0,1]$. Then  $$A:L^2(0,1)\rightarrow L^2(0,1)$$ $$f(x)\rightarrow \int_0^1{f(x)e^{-ixy}}dx, y\in[0,1]$$ 
is a compact operator.(this is a integral operator)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is $ \mathscr{B}(L^p(\mu),C(X))$ the space of bounded linear operators?

Comment: I'd say you'll have to use the 1st https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator#Important_properties

Comment: @JohnMa.yes, that is the space of all bounded linear operators.

Comment: @user1952009.you are right.I want to use the last formulation of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator#Important_properties.But I do not know how to find a cauchy subsequence. Do you have a idea?

Comment: @ByronSchmuland.Thank you for your help. Firstly, I think $\mathscr{B}(L^p(\mu),C(X))$ means all bounded linear operators from $L^p(\mu)$ to $C(X)$. Secondly, why do you think my example is not right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assume that $\mu$ is finite, otherwise take $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$, let $X$ be the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}$ and (identifying $L^p(X)$ with $L^p(\mathbb{R})$)
let $Af:=f*\rho$, where $\rho\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ and $\int\rho=1$.
Then $A$ maps $L^p(X)\to C(X)$ continuously (we use the fact that $f*\rho$ vanishes at infinity) but it is not compact from $L^p(X)$ to $L^p(X)$ (why?).

So let us assume $\mu(X)<\infty$. Let $(f_n)\subseteq L^p(\mu)$ be a bounded sequence. Since $L^p(\mu)$ is reflexive, we have $f_n\rightharpoonup f$ for some $f\in L^p(X)$ (up to subsequences), so we also have $Af_n\rightharpoonup Af$. Now for any $x\in X$
$$ (Af_n)(x)\to (Af)(x), $$
since evaluation at a point is a continuous functional on $C(X)$ and $Af_n$ is converging weakly to $Af$. Moreover $\|Af_n\|_\infty\le\|A\|\|f_n\|_p$,
so we can apply the dominated convergence theorem to conclude that
$$ \int_X |Af_n-Af|^p\,d\mu\to 0 $$
as $n\to\infty$ (here we are using the finiteness of $\mu$). So $Tf_n\to Tf$ in $L^p(X)$, proving the compactness of $T$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. what does $Af_n\rightarrow Af$ mean in your notations?

Comment: When I write $Af_n\rightharpoonup Af$ I mean weak convergence in $C(X)$. I used the (almost trivial) fact that if $f_n\rightharpoonup f$ then also $Af_n\rightharpoonup Af$ when $A$ is a bounded linear functional between two Banach spaces.

Comment: @Mizar.Nice! Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 7):

I take it you are assuming that $\mu(X)<\infty$; I don't think it works otherwise.

In this case, compose $T$ with point evaluation at $x\in X$ to obtain the bounded linear functional on $L^p$ that sends $f\mapsto (Tf)(x)$. This shows that there exists $K(x,\cdot)\in L^q$, $1/p+1/q=1$, with $\|K(x,\cdot)\|_q\le \|T\|$, such that
$$
(Tf)(x)= \int K(x,t)f(t)\, d\mu(t) .
$$
Now for $p=2$ everything is clear: $K\in L^2(X\times X)$, so the operator is Hilbert-Schmidt and in particular compact. For general $1<p<\infty$, a similar criterion is available; see the remark at the bottom of pg. 7 [of these notes.](http://www.terpconnect.umd.edu/~lvrmr/2008-2009-S/Classes/Amsc674.shtml)

Comment: .Thank you for your help. and How can you be sure that $K(x,y) $ is measurable and $ K(x,y)\in L^2(X\times X)$?

Comment: Measurability needs an argument, but it's intuitively that this can't possibly go wrong; $\|K\|_2^2=\int d\mu(x)\int d\mu(y)|K|^2\le \int \|T\|^2\, d\mu(x) = \|T\|^2\mu(X)$.

Comment: @Christian.yes, you are right. I think we need more information on $K$ for considering its measurabiility.